# add .bar bundle to existing blackberry app

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-world

I have an app which is for BlackBerry devices 7 and earlier. Now, I want to update that one with the new .cod file and also add .bar to support BB10 and PlayBook.

I added a release for the existing app with .cod, now I want to add the .bar, should I add a new product or another release? Can't I just add another file bundle to same release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new bundle to the same release, but make sure you target the 'QNX' platform.  That will provide you with the list of BlackBerry 10 & PlayBook devices, OS versions and carriers that you can target

Comment: I *think* you're saying the right thing, but I don't think your terminology is consistent with what the BlackBerry vendor portal uses.  The existing app will already have at least one approved "release".  Once a release is approved, you can't add new bundles to it.  You can only change the list of devices supported by those bundles.  If you have new code (new bundle) to upload, you have to create what they call a new "release" (i.e. a new version).  It's not a new app, but in their terminology, it's not "the same release".